# Opening multiple PowerPoint files (pps, ppsx) in single C# windows form

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a form with one input textbox to enter the names of the **pps/pssx** files separated by commas needed to open.

I split and store file names into an array and using `foreach` to loop through to open the files using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@item);
```

But it only opens one file at a time. 
Please advise a correct way to do this.

Comment: Just a guess, but if starting the process attempts to launch a new instance of PowerPoint each time, you'd get something like what you describe, since PPT allows only one instance of itself.  Instead, I think you'd have to launch PowerPoint, then automate it to open each of your files (you can have only one PPT instance, but that instance can have multiple documents open at one time, of course)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SteveRindsberg. Do you have any help resource in this particular PPT stuff for me to start?

Comment: Not for C#, but I'd imagine that a lot of the available information on the PowerPoint Object Model in VBA can be translated to C#.  I've got quite a few VBA examples on my PowerPoint FAQ page: http://www.pptfaq.com and scroll down to the programming section.